# Split one table's column into two columns based on value

Tags: regex, database-design, excel, vba

I have a table with **so many rows**. It's structure is like this picture:

[image]

As you can see i have "or", "And" between names in columns A. How i can splite these column into twi parts?. IN that case i will have David, Tylor, Fred, Jessi, Roland in the firstcolumn and Peter, Mark, Alfered, Hovard and DAvid in the second.

Note: Please pay attention to row 2 and 5. in these rows i have 2 "or" or two "and".

**Edit**: I prefer to do that in Excel

What I Have Tried

As one possible solution, i have this function in vba.

```
Function udfRegEx(CellLocation As Range, RegPattern As String)

Dim RegEx As Object, RegMatchCollection As Object, RegMatch As Object
Dim OutPutStr As String
Dim i As Integer

i = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorksheet.Name).UsedRange.rows.Count
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = RegPattern
    End With

        OutPutStr = ""
        Set RegMatchCollection = RegEx.Execute(CellLocation.Value)
        For Each RegMatch In RegMatchCollection
            OutPutStr = OutPutStr & RegMatch
        Next
        udfRegEx = OutPutStr

    Set RegMatchCollection = Nothing
    Set RegEx = Nothing
    Set Myrange = Nothing

End Function
```

This function uses Regex. but i  don't know how to use that.

Comment: how are you trying to split them? in excel? what is the output to? using what code?

Comment: @Droid. My data is in excel. thank you. i've updated the question

Comment: What Have you tried and where are you stuck? Are you confined toVBA or a formula will also help?

Comment: @SiddharthRout It doesn't Matter. A formula or VBA.

Comment: David, I can give you both but I want to first see what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for updating the post with what you have tried. Posting an Excel formula.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank you man. I've added one of possible solutions at the end of my question. What is important for me is to have these two column and knowing different methods is in the second importance level... .

Comment: Try the formula that I posted below. See if it works for you with every condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned that you do not need VBA for this. An Excel formula will also do what you need.

**My Assumptions**

1. Col A has the data
2. You want the output in Col B and Col C

Paste this formula in Cell B1 and copy it down

`=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(" or ",A1,1))=TRUE,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(" and ",A1,1))=TRUE,"",LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" and ",A1,1))),LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" or ",A1,1)))`

and this in Cell C1 and copy it down

`=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(" or ",A1,1))=TRUE,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(" and ",A1,1))=TRUE,"",MID(A1,SEARCH(" and ",A1,1)+5,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" and ",A1,1))),MID(A1,SEARCH(" or ",A1,1)+4,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" or ",A1,1)))`

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
(\w)+(( or | and ){0,1}(\w)+)*
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not a coding solution, but since you did not ask for code (and because its not necessary in this case), simply do a find/replace on the words "and" and "or" to replace them with some delimiter (e.g. replace them with a comma). Then in excel, you can select the data, and split them into different columns using excels "text to columns" feature (on the data tab in excel 2007).

Comment: find replace " and " and " or " with ","... otherwise Boris will become B,is... otherwise a good solution.

Comment: Text to columns based upon Space as delimeter will give 3 columns, delete the middle one :)